# Performance issues with more than 30 fields on a drupal 8 content type?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, paragraphs

[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbYyo.png)

I have a content type in a drupal 8 site with the layout as shown in the image, I have used css grid for the layout and every section( f1, f2, f3 ....) is a field which needs to have paragraph bundles in them (pb1, pb2, .......).

This is just one type of content type, i have another in which the amount of fields go up to 40+, not to forget the paragraph bundles in them which are a group of 3-4 paragraphs each.

I am concerned about the performance of the site now and later in time when the site grows, its a magazine site and content needs to be written everyday.

Any help appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: Is there any other way to get this layout, the stacking ability is required coz some of the fields need to come at the bottom in the mobile layout, so they all need to be in the same wrapper without nesting, css grid is the only way i found to achieve this, also i dont know how to reduce the number of fields :(

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on sites with hundreds of node fields and generally found that nesting them within collapsible fieldsets and having them collapsed by default, stopped the long wait for the field javascript handlers to all load and kick-in on the initial page load.

But that only works if you have collections of fields that you'll rarely have to edit.

Comment: yes, but in this case to get the desired layout the number of fields have shot up to 40, but i would like to mention that not all the fields will be used all the time.Longer the content then more are the fields used, so on an average i think 14-18 fields will be used for every node if not less, and this is the issue.Its not just one node, this is like the only content type to be used so i think there are 2 tables for every field, so 20 fields make close to 40 joins in mysql, close to 60 is the limit, :(